# Bootstrap elements cause a reduction in width, which is not a proper behavior

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

As title says some bootstrap elements changes my whole website width, reducing it by 15px.
I think that responsive elements cause this weird behavior.

Code:

```
  <div class="px-4 py-5 my-5 text-center">
    <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="{%static 'images/tinytools_logo.png'%}" alt="" width="100" height="100">
    <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-body-emphasis">Tiny Tools - AI powered platform</h1>
    <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
      <p class="lead mb-4">Have you ever dreamt of a website that can instantly answer your questions or help you solve
        a
        test? Our advanced platform, powered by the mighty GPT-4, is here to assist you.</p>
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container col-xxl-8 px-4">
    <div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse align-items-center g-5 ">
      <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
        <img src="{% static 'images/ask_gpt_logo.jpeg'%}" class="d-block mx-lg-auto img-fluid rounded-circle"
          alt="Bootstrap Themes" width="500" height="500" loading="lazy">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-body-emphasis lh-1 mb-3">Ask GPT - AI chatbot</h1>
        <p class="lead">AI chatbot powered by GPT-4 analyzes your question and provides precise answers based on the
          latest knowledge.</p>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg px-4 me-md-2">Tool</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
    <div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse align-items-center g-5">
      <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
        <img src="{% static 'images/lensgpt_logo.jpg'%}" class="d-block mx-lg-auto img-fluid rounded-circle"
          alt="Bootstrap Themes" width="500" height="500" loading="lazy">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-1">
        <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-body-emphasis lh-1 mb-3">Lens GPT - Test solver</h1>
        <p class="lead">Our GPT-4 intelligence analyzes the test content and generates answers to the questions within
          it.
        </p>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg px-4 me-md-2">Tool</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container px-4 py-5">
    <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-body-emphasis text-center border-bottom">Why to choose our website?</h1>

    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 align-items-md-center g-5 py-5">
      <div class="col d-flex flex-column align-items-start gap-2">
        <h2 class="fw-bold text-body-emphasis">Platform like never before</h2>
        <p class="text-body-secondary">Join us on this exhilarating journey where the fusion of passion and technology
          knows no bounds. As we continue to grow and improve, we invite you to be part of our community, where your
          feedback and ideas shape the future of our dynamic platform.

        </p>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Start</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 g-4">
          <div class="col d-flex flex-column gap-2">
            <div
              class="feature-icon-small d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-bg-warning bg-gradient fs-4 rounded-3"
              style="max-width: 48px; height: 48px">
              <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
                <use xlink:href="#tools" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <h4 class="fw-semibold mb-0 text-body-emphasis">GPT-4 Expertise</h4>
            <p class="text-body-secondary">Our website utilizes the latest version of artificial intelligence, GPT-4,
              which is an excellent companion for addressing your inquiries. With a 10-year track record in content
              creation, our platform is capable of delivering high-quality answers to a wide range of questions
            </p>

          </div>

          <div class="col d-flex flex-column gap-2">
            <div
              class="feature-icon-small d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-bg-warning bg-gradient fs-4 rounded-3"
              style="max-width: 48px; height: 48px">
              <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
                <use xlink:href="#speedometer2" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <h4 class="fw-semibold mb-0 text-body-emphasis">Speed and Efficiency</h4>
            <p class="text-body-secondary">We don't waste time. Input your question or upload a test image, and our
              website will provide you with answers or solutions in the blink of an eye. Regardless of the difficulty
              level, our platform is ready to assist you</p>


          </div>

          <div class="col d-flex flex-column gap-2">
            <div
              class="feature-icon-small d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-bg-warning bg-gradient fs-4 rounded-3"
              style="max-width: 48px; height: 48px">
              <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
                <use xlink:href="#people-circle" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <h4 class="fw-semibold mb-0 text-body-emphasis">User-Friendly</h4>
            <p class="text-body-secondary">Our website's interface is intuitive and user-friendly. Even if you're not
              tech-savvy, using our platform is simple and convenient</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col d-flex flex-column gap-2">
            <div
              class="feature-icon-small d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-bg-warning bg-gradient fs-4 rounded-3"
              style="max-width: 48px; height: 48px">
              <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
                <use xlink:href="#geo-fill" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <h4 class="fw-semibold mb-0 text-body-emphasis">Security and Privacy</h4>
            <p class="text-body-secondary">We care about your data. All information you provide on our website is
              treated
              with the utmost confidentiality. You don't have to worry about your privacy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Full code: [Gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/vilis/tiny-tools/-/blob/ask_gpt/tiny_tools/tiny_tools/templates/features.html?ref_type=heads)

I tried to remove all but one element. Then col-lg-6 caused the problem. Removing it caused proper behavior. But I have more elements on the page, deleting all responsive elements didn't fix the problem.

Comment: after 3 hours of trying , I have found a solution:
scrollbar causes the problem.
solution:
html {
      scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges;
    }